# Apache FlexUnit socket timeout

Tags: ant, timeout, flexunit

I'm using Apache FlexUnit 4.1 and Ant to run my unit tests for my AS3 app. Here is my ant setup : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9329872.

Tests are correctly executed but the ant process never stops and displays an error :

```
Buildfile: /Users/ymichel/FlashApp/UnitTest/build.xml

test:
    [mxmlc] Loading configuration file /Users/ymichel/Packages/flex-sdk/frameworks/flex-config.xml
    [mxmlc] /Users/ymichel/FlashApp/UnitTest/build/player-test.swf (72863 bytes)

BUILD FAILED
/Users/ymichel/FlashApp/UnitTest/build.xml:37: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Socket timeout waiting for flexunit report
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at org.flexunit.ant.tasks.TestRun.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.flexunit.ant.tasks.FlexUnitTask.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: Socket timeout waiting for flexunit report
    at org.flexunit.ant.FlexUnitSocketServer.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.flexunit.ant.FlexUnitSocketThread.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:439)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:468)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:436)
    at org.flexunit.ant.FlexUnitSocketServer.openClientSocket(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more

Total time: 1 minute 3 seconds
```

I'm probably the biggest noob on earth but I'm completely unable to say why... Please help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I add all FlexUnit .swc, no error occurs. Add this to your build.xml :

```
    <library-path dir="${FLEXUNIT_HOME}" append="true">
        <include name="**/target/*.swc"/>
    </library-path>
```

instead

```
    <library-path dir="${FLEXUNIT_HOME}/FlexUnit4/target/" append="true">
        <include name="*.swc"/>
    </library-path>
```